# Array missing in Variable View window with Xcode

Tags: xcode, arrays, debugging

I have a local array and I'd like to take a look at the contents with Xcode 4.3.2.  The array does not appear in the Variable View window, so I don't know how I can access it, either through the Variable View window or through a memory window.  I can create a pointer to the array and view memory that way, but that seems like unnecessary work.  Other variables are working just fine.  Here's the code:

```
int width = 32;
int height = 24;
unsigned int testData[width * height];
unsigned int *ptr = &testData[0];
```

The width, height, and ptr variables appear in the Variable View window, but not testData.  What am I missing with Xcode?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LLDB, switch back to GDB. LLDB is still not entirely ready for prime time.

(Edit your scheme, choose the Run action, and in the "Info" tab, you can choose which debugger to use.)

Also: Make sure you are debugging a "debug" build, with no optimizations. The "Optimization Level" build setting should be "None [-O0]". Higher optimization levels can confuse any debugger.

Comment: I switched to GDB and double checked that the debug build is using [-O0], but I still see the same behavior.  Perhaps I should have mentioned it, but I am building for an iOS device.